# web base accounting application

Tags: php, ajax, oracle, oracle9i, ajaxform

I want to build a web Base application for accounting company with large amount of data that doing task like following

1-login page.
2- Inquiry account Details like (Account Owner Name, Account number, Balance, date,..personal information and account information.. etc ) by entering the primary key account number and then display to user some details 
3- reports something like this example of [Datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)
and these reports should be exported to excel file or PDF file (I don't know if that possible in some way)

**Notes**

the system is running with oracle data

I want to know if using **PHP** to enhance the security and ajax technique to enhance the preference of querying data is good way to design my web base application or should I use something better

finally I you don't mind to give me a good explained example for above ideas or 
for the suggests ideas specifically example that using  liked to oracle database

I searched and found examples that use PHP ajax and jquery or bootstrap with MySQL

I also want to know what the difference between them and which is better in my case

Comment: Please unvote me coz i got blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this, because I feel comfortable with those languages, this kind of application can be created in a lot of languages, so why not go with those you are good at  ->
 Backend: PHP, mysql
 Frontend: html, css, js, bootstrap

I would use ajax if there is need for posting data and updating elements without refresh.

But this is just me, do it with what you feel comfortable, but prepare everything before u start, create ER model for database based on as much info you can get, create business logic process and procedures before you start coding so you do not end up writing the same code multiple times.
Hope this helps

Comment: Why _"would you do it like this?"_ A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @bub moot point since it's not a good question for SO in the first place.